# I'm unable to get WiEngine skeleton project to run

Tags: java, android, static-linking, cocos2d-android

So I'm trying to port some cocos2d iOS apps over to Android and it looks like WiEngine is the most fully featured port of cocos2d to android ( http://www.wiyun.com/web/wiengine ), however I'm having issues getting the skeleton project to run. The latest problem I'm running into is I get a "Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown while initializing Lcom/wiyun/engine/skeleton/Skeleton" error in the ADB. I'm trying to run it in the emulator which also may be an issue. I'm kind of stuck because i need to see if I can get certain things to work (particle effects etc) before i can justify a hardware purchase.

Originally I tried to import the Skeleton project into eclipse but ran into too many errors so i created a blank android project with the same package name as the skeleton project and added the libraries to the build path through properties>libraries>add external Jars

the project compiles but it crashes as soon as it tries to initialize the Skeleton class here is the console stuff:

http://pastebin.com/XAc0XYiA

Appreciate any help on this.

Thanks,

Nick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to include JNI accessible precompiled libraries to you project. You can find them on the SDK archive.

[image]

Comment: So i've added the .so files as suggested and it seems the same, one thing im seeing is you have 2 .jar files as well and mine have different icons. i also am not sure if im supposed to add these .so files to the build path? I'm really new to eclipse and android so I appreciate the help here, im not finding anything in google that explains the correct method to include these files in the android project. here is a screenshot: http://homepage.mac.com/knyck2/eclipseShot.png thanks again for the help

Comment: I got it not sure what exactly I changed but i definitely did not include the .so files in the build path and just added the 2 .jars as you have shown here. Thanks again. Oh, also I put up the skeleton project on git if anyone wants it: https://github.com/nickthedude/WiEngine-Skeleton-

Answer (score 0):

For running your WiEngine Projects you have to add the WiEngine Library which is available when you download it from Github.

https://github.com/stubma/WiEngine

You can add library:
Right click on your Project-> Properties->Android->Library->Add WiEngine